# Automatically save documents to a specific folder

Tags: windows-xp, script, document-management

I'm doing an internship at a nonprofit organization. There is a share folder setup for employees to save their work to. Unfortunately, many of them forget to save to the share and instead save to their machines.

Is there any way (like using a script) that will automatically save the documents to the share folder instead of the hard drive?

The computers have Windows XP.

Comment: There are a number of considerations to be made. How will the script know where to look on their machines for any given file? are there common directories and file name constructs in use? Do you have active directory setup?

Comment: What application are they using?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the default location of the `Save As` button of all Microsoft applications (e.g Word, Excel) and other application that use the default Windows `Save As` dialogue (e.g Notepad++):

[image: Windows XP default Save As dialogue]

It is possible to change location to whatever directory you want, including a network share or mapped drive:

1. Open `REGEDIT` (Start -> Run -> regedit) and browse to
   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User
   Shell\Folders.br`.
2. Edit the string value `Personal` and change the data to whatever directory or other location you want. No special syntax is needed.
3. Press the F5 key to refresh. If that did not work, close all open programs and hit F5 again.

This will work for all MS applications, including Windows itself, with a few exceptions.
If you want to do the same for other programs, that use a different/custom `Save As` dialogue, you might need to change the `Save As` location manually for each program, usually through its settings or preferences.

Comment: This will work for any apps that call the windows built-in save-as dialog, but not for those that use alternative gui toolkits or custom save-as dialogs.

Comment: Right, I added this info to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the local directory and replace it with a [shortcut](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Create-or-delete-a-shortcut) to the shared directory using the local directory's name. Shortcuts are transparent to most applications so no further work should be necessary.